# Flex: Send XML content with HTML entities to PHP via POST

Tags: php, xml, apache-flex, post

I developed a desktop AIR application which saves data locally as XML files.
When the user clicks a button, the xml content is posted to a PHP application, where data is handled (inserted or updated).

The problem is, when I post some data containing html entities like & or >, the xml content is not parsed.

I'm using this class to parse the xml content:
https://sites.google.com/site/floweringmind/home

This is the input:

```
<companie_ps>
  <denCompanie>Company &amp; Friends</denCompanie>
  <email>abc@abc.ro</email>
</companie_ps>
```

This is the wanted result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [denCompanie] => Company & Friends
            [email] => abc@abc.ro
        )

)
```

This is the actual result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [denCompanie] => Array
                (
                    [@content] => Company
                )

        )

)
```

Error message: XML parse error 68 'XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED' at line 5, column 28 (byte index 63).

**EDIT**: The problem came from the fact that the post was converting html entities inside xml tags contents to actual characters. So, I used a regex to replace the special characters with their html entities. This is the code, in case someone will need it:

```
function _handle_match($match)
{
  return '<' . $match[1] . '>' . htmlentities($match[2]) . '</' . $match[3] . '>';
}

$pattern = "/\<(.*)\>(.*?)\<\/(.*)\>/imU";
$xml = preg_replace_callback($pattern, '_handle_match', $xml);
```

Comment: Great that you're showing the input, the wanted result, and the actual result. Can you also show some of the code (AIR and PHP) that is posting, and receiving, the XML? Also you didn't mention whether the error at the top of your post comes out of the AIR app or the PHP. (I'm guessing the latter.)

Comment: You're right, the error came from PHP. Problem was fixed, as I stated in the post edit. Thank you.